# How to populate a Tree with flat JSON?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am receiving a JSON response from an API with the following objects structure:

```
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "name": "Root Company Ltd.",
            "guid": "{1760F250-5012-46B2-8BBF-955FFD1C51AD}",
            "parentGuid": null,
            "active": true,
            "connected": true
        },
        {
            "name": "25-Tecvoz HLV1WAD",
            "guid": "{CC893441-A3B5-42B2-95B6-F3E56F0286AE}",
            "parentGuid": "{1760F250-5012-46B2-8BBF-955FFD1C51AD}",
            "active": true,
            "connected": true
        },
        {
            "name": "20-Axis M1031",
            "guid": "{216142B2-A9B8-4AFF-85CD-1D97685F4EE1}",
            "parentGuid": "{1760F250-5012-46B2-8BBF-955FFD1C51AD}",
            "active": true,
            "connected": true
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the JSON structure is "flat", the object's children are not nested to their parents, but when building the tree panel, objects with `parentGuid` set should be nested to an object with the matching `guid`.

The tree also doesn't need to be dynamic, I mean it doesn't need to make a new request to the server every time I open a node, as this JSON is the complete set of information from the server already.

I am using the following Model:

```
Ext.define('Web.model.Server', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [
               'Web.globals'
               ],
    idProperty: 'guid',

    // "fields" and "validators" skipped...

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: Web.globals.getAddress('/api/servers'),
        appendId: false,

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'servers'
        }
    }
});
```

The Store:

```
Ext.define('Web.store.Servers', {
    /* URL /api/servers */
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    alias: 'store.servers',
    model: 'Web.model.Server',
    root: {expanded: true}
});
```

And the Panel:

```
{
    xtype : 'treepanel',
    name : 'Servers',
    title : 'Select the server',
    flex : 1,
    overflowY : 'scroll',
    autoScroll : true,
    margin : 5,
    store : Ext.create('Web.store.Servers'),
    rootVisible : false,
    displayField: 'name',
    autoLoad: true,                         
}
```

How can I accomplish this? I wasn't able to find a clear way in the documentation.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-parentIdProperty

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Alright, seems to work! But still, after rendering is complete, there are just nodes. How would I turn nodes without children into leaves? I added `{ name: 'leaf', type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true}` to the model's fields, but the tree didn't render then.